# Set difference of two dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set-difference

I hope someone can help with an answer to this question. Similar questions have been asked before, but their answers are not completely correct, even the selected ones.

I would like to get the set difference of two Pandas dataframes. Meaning, `df1 - df2` equals rows that are present in `df1` but not present in `df2`. Any rows that are in `df1` but not in `df2` must be in the result. Rows in common must not be in the result. Classic set difference definition.

Also, indices must be ignored. This means the equality of two rows must be determined by:

1) whether they have the same column names (which is satisfied if their containing dataframes do) and,

2) if 1 is true, whether for each column their values are exactly the same (string-match - okay, we can consider case-insensitivity too)

Examples in other questions are simplified ones and while they may work in their limited scope, they do not work for all cases. Please try to think of  cases where values in a column might not be simple data types, but lists or tuples themselves. Or if someone later defines a custom type and its `equals` method, the solution works with those types too.

Comment: Have you consider sharing with us an example of dfs you want to compare?

Comment: Probably with some join, possibly using a compound key covering all columns. Please show sample data, to make this an MCVE. Just something small and representative. Also 1) is kind of irrelevant, all rows in df1 will have the same columns. And your requirement "indices must be ignored" may be a bad idea, we may want a compound row index so we can detect equality. *"Examples in other questions... do not work for all cases."* That's way too generalized and you didn't provide any MCVE. Should we really have a Unicode-case-insensitive matching on all string columns? Comparing different encodings?

Comment: There are [290 existing questions on *identical rows dataframes*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=identical+rows+dataframes+is%3Aq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try hashing the rows and then checking

Ex.

```
df1['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
df2['match'] = df2.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
df_diff = df1[~df1['match'].isin(df2['match'])]
```